# Export GeoTIFF with pixel min max value from GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, arcgis-pro, export

this is a question folllowing up with my previous question [Export raster with its min max range from GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348655/export-raster-with-its-min-max-range-from-gee) and [Export raster with its min max range from GEE 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348664/export-raster-with-its-min-max-range-from-gee-2). I need to export the GeoTIFF with pixels in the raster layer keep their index value so I can use it in ArcGIS. Below is the code I tried from @Kuik's answer and his link:

```
var visualizeMinMaxNDVI = function(maskImage) {
  var minMax = maskImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
  bestEffort: true,
});
  var visParams = {
          min: minMax.getNumber('NDVI_min'),
          max: minMax.getNumber('NDVI_max'),
          palette:'green'
          };
  return maskImage.visualize(visParams)
            .set({min: minMax.getNumber('NDVI_min'), max: minMax.getNumber('NDVI_max')});
};

// set visualization parameters based on min and max value
var NDVIvis = maskImage.map(function(maskImage){
  return visualizeMinMaxNDVI(maskImage);
});
print(NDVIvis);
// Export a cloud-optimized GeoTIFF.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: maskImage,
  description: '21072016UNDVI',
  scale: 10,
  region: table,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
```

I got error `maskImage.map is not a function.`

Also, how can I put `visParams` into `Export.image.toDrive` now (since `visParams` is a parameter in the function). 
If you want to see my previous code please check the links at the start. Sorry for codes all over the place....

Comment: the function expects a single image as input. You can only map over an image collection. Just try `var newImge = visualizeMinMaxNDVI(maskImage);`

Comment: Hi @Kuik thanks for your comment. I have tried the code and somehow when I import the Geotiff in ArcGIS the stats (min, max, mean and std) were stretched with in 0-255 range instead of the original NDVI pixel value..I have asked a new questiona and posted my code (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350094/pixel-value-in-export-geotiff-file-stretched-by-color-value).